# Submit data to single row of a mysql DB through a PHP foreach-looped button

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

I am displaying a mysql table on a website by looping through it using php's `foreach` construct like:

```
<?php foreach($bills as $bills): ?>
   <tr>
      <td><?= $bills->column1; ?></td>
      <td><?= $bills->valid; ?></td>
      <td><?= $button; ?></td>
   </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

The column named `valid` is set to `varchar(1)`, so its values are either `y` or `n` to define if a bill is valid or invalid.

By default for every row the column named `valid` is set to `n` – by clicking the button of a row i want to set the `valid` value of the specific row to `y` but i am a bit lost on how to pass the data the proper way.

The `$button` variable contains following html code:

```
<form id="submit">
   <button type="submit">Valid</button>
</form>
```

Clicking the button runs the ajax script below:

```
<script>
   $('#submit').click(function() {
      $.ajax({
         url: 'connect.php',
         type: 'POST',
         data: null,
         success: function(msg) {
            alert('Success ');
         }
      });
   });
</script>
```

connect.php runs the following code:

```
<?php include('../config.php') ?>

<?php 
   $query = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE bills SET valid='y'");
   $query->execute();
?>
```

My guess would be that i have to send a variable through ajax's `data` option and then call it in the mysql query like

```
UPDATE bills SET valid='y' WHERE variablefromajax = id
```

but as i mentioned above i'm a bit clueless on how to check which specific button has been clicked and then pass that information.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, since you plan to have multiple buttons, make sure each button has two HTML attributes:

- `data-row-id="<ID of the row>"`
- specific class,like class="row-submitter"

then, change your logic a bit to track the class clicks, not ID:

```
$('.row-submitter').click(function() {
      $.ajax({
         url: 'connect.php',
         type: 'POST',
         data: null,
         success: function(msg) {
            alert('Success ');
         }
      });
   });
```

thanks to the fact that button also had ID data on it's attribute you can now say:

```
$('.row-submitter').click(function() {
      $.ajax({
         url: 'connect.php',
         type: 'POST',
         data: "id="+$(this).data('row-id')+'&value=newvalue',
         success: function(msg) {
            alert('Success ');
         }
      });
   });
```

and use them like

```
   $query = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE bills SET valid='".$_POST['value']."' where id=".$_POST['id']."");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the data using get request. Like:

```
<script>
   $('#submit').click(function() {
      $.ajax({
         url: 'connect.php?ifvalid=y',
         type: 'GET',
         data: null,
         success: function(msg) {
            alert('Success ');
         }
      });
   });
</script>
```

and in your php file you can get it with `$_REQUEST['ifvalid']` and then you can conditionally make changes in the database.